# Subset rows incrementaly from different files

Tags: r, subset

I have a couple of files (60) containing tables with identical column names. I write down an exemple of three of them.

what I need is to read from each file  (for(i in files) source(i) ?) the data and create a single table out of them where I extract for each ID one single row (with all variables) from each file. The first row starts at a certain date which gets incremented in the next files by one.

For instance, the "starting" row in the first file would be row no. 10 , which start on 10th of Jan.
10 ID1 2000-01-10   20

Now, I jump to the next file, I search for the same ID and subset the row no. 11 (incremented by one day) which represents the dates from the next day,  2000-01-11
Step to the next file, the same ID, subset the row no. 12 (incremented by one compared to the previous file), etc.
The number of rows to be subsetted for each ID equals files number. The iteration goes till we reach all rows for ID1 or the last file.
Then, we repeat the operations above for  the next ID, namely ID2 where the starting row comes from the first file as well and has the same starting date as ID1. It is also row number 10 relative to its ID but 22 in the file:  22 = 10 (ID1 + 2 incremental).

```
 Day =  seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), length = 12, by = "days")                
file1: 
set.seed(123)
  df1 <- data.frame( rowid =  c(1:24),
          ID = c("ID1", "ID1","ID1", "ID1","ID1", "ID1","ID1", "ID1",  "ID1", "ID1","ID1", 
              "ID1","ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2","ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2","ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2"),
          Date =  rep(Day, 2),
          Var1 = sample(1:30, 24, TRUE) )
file2:
set.seed(123)
   df2 <- data.frame( rowid =  c(1:24),
              ID = c("ID1", "ID1","ID1", "ID1","ID1", "ID1","ID1", "ID1",  "ID1", "ID1","ID1", "ID1","ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2","ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2","ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2"),
              Date =  rep(Day, 2),
              Var1 = sample(40:60, 24, TRUE))
file3:
set.seed(123)
  df3 <- data.frame(rowid =  c(1:24),
              ID = c("ID1", "ID1","ID1", "ID1","ID1", "ID1","ID1", "ID1",  "ID1", "ID1","ID1", "ID1","ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2","ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2","ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2"),
              Date =  rep(Day, 2),
              Var1 = sample(70:100, 24, TRUE))
```

The output should look like:

```
              10 ID1 2000-01-10   20
              11 ID1 2000-01-11   44
              12 ID1 2000-01-12   83
              22 ID2 2000-01-10    9
              23 ID2 2000-01-11   50
              24 ID2 2000-01-12   98
```

Any thought on how to get it?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use the following solution. For this I first find the starting `Date` and then I used `map2` function to iterate along data sets as well as Date's increments:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(magrittr)

df_list %>%
  map2_dfr(0:(length(df_list)-1), ~ .x %>% 
             group_by(ID) %>% 
             filter(Date == df_list %>%
                      map(~ .x %>% 
                            filter(rowid == start) %>% 
                            pull(Date)) %>%
                      extract2(1) + .y)) %>%
  arrange(ID)

# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   ID [2]
  rowid ID    Date        Var1
  <int> <chr> <date>     <int>
1    10 ID1   2000-01-10    20
2    11 ID1   2000-01-11    44
3    12 ID1   2000-01-12    83
4    22 ID2   2000-01-10     9
5    23 ID2   2000-01-11    50
6    24 ID2   2000-01-12    98
```

In case you had already `rbind` all of your data sets instead of gathering them in a list you can use this:

```
df %>%
  group_split(ID) %>%
  map_dfr(~ .x %>% 
            filter(Date == df %>%
                     filter(rowid == start) %>%
                     pull(Date) %>% extract2(1) + 0:2)) %>%
  group_split(Date) %>% 
  map2_dfr(1:length(.), ~ .x %>% 
             group_by(rowid, ID) %>% 
             slice(n = .y)) %>%
  arrange(ID)

# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   rowid, ID [6]
  rowid ID    Date        Var1
  <int> <chr> <date>     <int>
1    10 ID1   2000-01-10    20
2    11 ID1   2000-01-11    44
3    12 ID1   2000-01-12    83
4    22 ID2   2000-01-10     9
5    23 ID2   2000-01-11    50
6    24 ID2   2000-01-12    98
```

Comment: Thank you, it works .  But how the solution   would look like if instead of having a list of files, I create a huge data frame by binding the rows into a df <- rbind (df1, df2, df2) ?

Comment: Check my updates please. You just have to pay attention to `0:2` in second solution I wanted to specify that in a 3 data frame set we actually add `1` and `2` to our initial `Date` which is `2000-01-10`. But it is actually ranges from `0` to number of your data frames minus `1` so you can modify it yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much . This solution works  as well.  The problem  occurs though when the data from each df has  different number of rows. In this case, the returned values are not the correct one.  for instance, reducing the second data df2<- df2[1:20, ] . Any idea on how to do it properly?

Comment: The second solution was quite a very specific case I managed to get to the desired output cause the rows in all three resulting data sets are of equal numbers. Is it possible for you to store them in a list instead of `rbind`ing them. Cause I think in that cause my first solution and other solutions you get will work without any problem.

Answer (score 4):

Preparing your input like so:

```
df_list <- list(df1, df2, df3)
start <- 10
```

You could do:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

imap_dfr(df_list, \(file, index) split(file, ~ ID) %>%
     map_dfr(~ slice(.x, start - 1 + index))) %>%
  arrange(ID)
```

Which returns the desired:

```
  rowid  ID       Date Var1
1    10 ID1 2000-01-10   20
2    11 ID1 2000-01-11   44
3    12 ID1 2000-01-12   83
4    22 ID2 2000-01-10    9
5    23 ID2 2000-01-11   50
6    24 ID2 2000-01-12   98
```

Comment: Concise and elegant.

Answer (score 2):

I would have done it like this,

```r
Day =  seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), length = 12, by = "days")                

set.seed(123)
df1 <- data.frame( rowid =  c(1:24),
                   ID = c("ID1", "ID1","ID1", "ID1","ID1", "ID1","ID1", "ID1",  "ID1", "ID1","ID1", 
                          "ID1","ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2","ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2","ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2"),
                   Date =  rep(Day, 2),
                   Var1 = sample(1:30, 24, TRUE) )
set.seed(123)
df2 <- data.frame( rowid =  c(1:24),
                   ID = c("ID1", "ID1","ID1", "ID1","ID1", "ID1","ID1", "ID1",  "ID1", "ID1","ID1", "ID1","ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2","ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2","ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2"),
                   Date =  rep(Day, 2),
                   Var1 = sample(40:60, 24, TRUE))
set.seed(123)
df3 <- data.frame(rowid =  c(1:24),
                  ID = c("ID1", "ID1","ID1", "ID1","ID1", "ID1","ID1", "ID1",  "ID1", "ID1","ID1", "ID1","ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2","ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2","ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2"),
                  Date =  rep(Day, 2),
                  Var1 = sample(70:100, 24, TRUE))


df_list <- list(df1, df2, df3)
start <- 10
library(tidyverse)

reduce(df_list[-1], .init = df_list[[1]] %>% filter(Date == Date[rowid == start]), 
       ~bind_rows(..1, ..2 %>% filter(Date == 1 + max(..1$Date)) ))

#>   rowid  ID       Date Var1
#> 1    10 ID1 2000-01-10   20
#> 2    22 ID2 2000-01-10    9
#> 3    11 ID1 2000-01-11   44
#> 4    23 ID2 2000-01-11   50
#> 5    12 ID1 2000-01-12   83
#> 6    24 ID2 2000-01-12   98
```

---

Try this!

```
reduce2(df_list[-1], seq_along(df_list[-1]), .init = df_list[[1]] %>% filter(Date == Date[rowid == start]), 
       ~bind_rows(..1, ..2 %>% filter(Date == ..3 + min(..1$Date)) ))
```

Comment: Thank you. The solution worss very well for the format I provided.  But, I actualy need to create the list out of many  xlsx files and then apply your code. In this case, I got different results.

Comment: Thank you the solution works well for the format I provided. I actualy need to create  first the list out of many xlsx files,  then apply your code. In this case, I got different results. I savied dfi on the disk  on separate files:  writexl::write_xlsx(df3, "path/df3.xlsx"), etc then read the filenames with listfiles <-  list.files(path = "path", pattern = ".xlsx$", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE).  Then read the files into a list of data frames: list_tible <- lapply(listfile, read_excel) and finaly create the list,df_list<- list (files1, file2, file3) . I don't know where is the mistake

Comment: Thank you for asking me. I have issues with the my files therefore I'm trying to solve it differently, by creating a single data frame/table out of them. I posted the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68069242/subset-rows-with-increasing-index-r

Comment: Thank you, I got the same result. I give up and try to solve it as mentioned above in the link. you could have a look there if you want

Comment: @gogo88 I couldn't understand that question??