# Subset rows with increasing index - R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to find a solution to my problem and noticed I have provided a false example in the previous post.
I need to subset some data which has the folowing structure:

1. it comes originaly from many data frames which have the same columns and number of rows.
2. I have simulated it in the example below:

   ```
   library(purrr)
   library(dplyr)

   Day =  seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), length = 12, by = "days")

   set.seed(123)
   df1 <- data.frame( Category = c("ID1", "ID1","ID1", "ID1","ID1", "ID1","ID1", "ID1",  "ID1", "ID1","ID1", "ID1"),
                      Date =  Day )
   df1

   set.seed(123)
   df2 <- data.frame( Category = c("ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2","ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2","ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2"),
                      Date =  Day)

   set.seed(123)
   df3 <- data.frame( Category = c("ID3", "ID3","ID3", "ID3","ID3", "ID3","ID3", "ID3",  "ID3", "ID3","ID3", "ID3"),
                      Date =  Day)

   df <- rbind(df1, df2, df3)
   df <- map_dfr(seq_len(3), ~df) 
   df <- df %>% 
       mutate(rowid = 1:nrow(df))
   ```

I define a bunch as being the data which comes originaly from each data frame. It consist of three
IDs: ID1, ID2, ID3. In this data there are 3 bunches.
A starting date is given and is the same for each ID, like  starting_date = 2000-01-10.

From each bunch I need to extract one single row for each ID starting with the starting_date and iterating in the next bunch for the next day. In each bunch we increase the index for the row/Date by one. This increment is fixed, 37,  as it is given by (left_ID1_rows + ID2_rows + ID3_rows + next_ID1_position)  = 2 +12+12+11

For instance: ID1 , starts at 2000-01-10. Next bunch we need to pick up the value from Date+1 = 2000-01-11. The thirds row will be at the Date+2 = 2000-01-12 etc.
The same should be done with ID2 and ID3.

I have created the output as it should look like.

```
  Category   Date         rowid
   ID1        2000-01-10    10
   ID1        2000-01-11    47
   ID1        2000-01-12    84
   ID2        2000-01-10    22
   ID2        2000-01-11    59
   ID2        2000-01-12    96
   ID3        2000-01-10    34
   ID3        2000-01-11    71
   ID3        2000-01-12   108
```

The are two increments:

1. the one between ID1, ID2, ID3 is constant and equal to 12 (length(Category))
2. the one between the same IDs (first three rows in the output above) is also constant and equal 37.

I have tried the folowings sugested in another post:

```
   df %>% group_by(Category) %>% slice(seq(10, n(), 37)) %>% ungroup
```

which pickup only the first position for each ID

or

```
        df[ave(logical(nrow(df)), df1$Category, FUN=function(i) `[<-`(i,seq(start, length(i), constant), TRUE)),]
```

which subset only ID1s

Another way of seing the problems will be:

1.) define the bunchs length (36)

2.) define the starting_date= 2000-01-10

3.) iterate over bunches:

3.1) extract from the first bunch all IDs  for which Date = starting_date

3.2) increment starting_date= starting_date + 1

3.3) move to the next bunch
3.4) repeat steps 3.1-3.2 till the last bunch

I hope it is more clear .
Any idea on how to do it? I can't use the list, I need to work with a sigle data frame/tabel as described above.
Thank you

Comment: Are the `Category` values (`"ID1"`, `"ID2"`, etc.) each unique to their "bunch"?  That is, will every row in the 1st bunch have `"ID1"`, every row in the 2nd bunch have `"ID2"`, and so on?

Comment: Yes, every bunch has unique values for the IDs. In fact, every row is unique. I should have add another column to make this clear but we can think of the rowid not as an index but as another variable. I added it like this to be easily to track the results

Comment: OK...so if you specify `starting_date <- 2000-01-10`, you want R to (1) extract the row (if any) from the 1st "bunch" (ie. with a `Category` of `"ID1"`) whose date is `2000-01-10`; then (2) extract the row (if any) from the 1st bunch (`"ID1"`) whose date `2000-01-11` comes one day later; then (3) extract the row (if any) from the 1st bunch (`"ID1"`) whose date `2000-01-12` comes another day later. You then want R to repeat this for the next two batches (`"ID2"` and `"ID3"`). If one of those days does not exist in a bunch (`2000-01-12` for `"ID2"`), you want to skip only that day in that bunch.

Comment: Also, since `map_dfr(seq_len(3), ~df)` creates triplicates, which are only distinguished by `rowid`, it is problematic when distinguishing records within bunches.  How should R know to extract row 46 (`ID1` | `2000-01-11` | `46`) from your example `df`, rather than row 11 (`ID1` | `2000-01-11` | `11`)? When extracting this second date in the bunch, should R choose the row that has the second-lowest `rowid` for this date? Yet if `rowid` is simply any old variable, we can't rely on it to distinguish triplicates created from the same (say) `df1`.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I realized the issue is confused. I will change the question and try to clarify it. In order to simplify it I consider the bunches have the same number of rows which will make the search for the next IDs position to depend on a fixed number.